# Metamask getBalance method doesnt work

Tags: metamask, dapps, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dapp-development

When I wanted show my eth balance in my web site it gives me this "0x103cf17cc1518eb4" how can i turn into string?

Comment: You can use `parseInt("0x103cf17cc1518eb4")` , also try `BigInt("0x103cf17cc1518eb4")`

Comment: BigInt worked thx the other one showed 1.9 ..... something which I have 1.1 ...... something like that thanks anyway

Comment: yeah, parseInt works for smaller numbers, but balances usually are BigNumbers, that's why BigInt worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigInt worked. Thanks to Zartaj Afser.